# Autodoc FR (ADFR), Installation on MacOS BIG SUR

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation, macos-big-sur

I am trying to install Autodoc FR (ADFR), on MacOS BIG SUR, but every time I am getting popup window saying

> Python 2.7 cant be opened because the developer cannot be verified,

I even allow for security and privacy, however again the same popup shows up.

My command line is

```
mdumar@Mds-MacBook-Pro ADFRsuite_x86_64Darwin_1.0 % ./install.sh -d /Users/mdumar/Desktop/docking  -c 0
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @LaurenFitch, no I didnt figure it out, i think autodock is not working on Mac OS, I did my work on Window, better u use Autodock Vinna, it Will work, or U can Use Chimera Tool for Docking, its easy to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issues on MacOs Ventura. My hardware is a MacBookPro M2. How I worked around the issue was on `System Settings/Privacy & Security/Developer Tools`. Then I added `iTerm` (or `Terminal`) app, this is going to "allow iTerm (or `Terminal`) to run software locally that does not meet the system's security policy". For installation I used: `./install.sh -d ~/ADFRsuite-1.0 -c 0`